# Object clone() getMethods java

Tags: java

Проблема заключается в том, что я хочу вывести названия методов моего класса.
Но при таком коде, метод clone() не определяется как метод класса, почему?
И когда я пытаюсь переопределить метод clone() (попытка в комментариях), в выводе получается уже два clone(), почему? У меня предположение что один clone это по умолчанию, а другой - мой.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class task9Obj implements Cloneable{
 /*  private int a = 5;
    public task9Obj clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
        task9Obj t = new task9Obj();
        t.a=6;
        return t;
    }*/

    public static String[] getMethodsNames(Object obj){
        Class cl = obj.getClass();                                      
        Method[] mtds = cl.getMethods();                                
        String[] methods = new String[mtds.length];                     
        for (int i=0; i<mtds.length; ++i){
            methods[i]=mtds[i].getName();
        }
        return methods;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        task9Obj st = new task9Obj();                             
        String[] arr = getMethodsNames(st);                 
        for (int i=0; i< arr.length; ++i){
            System.out.println(arr[i]);                     
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. 

```
вам нужно переопределить метод класа Object вот так, все потому что метод уже зарезервирован с определеной сигнатурой и может быть только переопределен как указано ниже.


 @Override
        protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
            return super.clone();
        }
```